# PostgreSQL servers are visible by PgAdmin even I deleted them. They were installed by homebrew

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I installed postgresql into MacOS m1 Ventura with homebrew and then deleted them. However they are displayed by the pgadmin and I can not enter as they are are deleted, but diplayed. [image]

Ansar Todo and PostgreSQL 14 were installed by the homebrew and then deleted. I run "brew services list" it return that there is no services. I thought that some not deletable folders are left when I deleted them. However, when I check homebrew foder, there is no postgres, and when I check Application folder, there is also no such postgresql versions.

How can I resolves this issue?

Comment: Remove them from pgadmin if you don't want to see them anymore in pgadmin.

Comment: There is no technical issue, the only issue is understanding what you are seeing. First off Postgres and pgAdmin are totally separate entities, one a RDBMS the other a client app. Inside the client app (pgAdmin) you create connections (registrations?) to be used when connecting to a database. What you see are the available connection definitions and that they are closed, indicated by the red x. pgAdmin does not access/open a connection until selected. So is unaware the connection point has been removed. You simply need to delete the connection.